# Oracle Clave primaria vs Clave única vs Índice único

Tags: sql, oracle, rendimiento, indices

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia (en caso de existir) entre las claves primarias y un índice marcado como único (**Primary Key** vs **Unique Index**).

Según veo, ambos terminan creando un índice sobre determinado campo, pero desconozco si afecta en algo el *rendimiento* (teniendo N cantidad de datos) para poder consultar los datos.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Index ON dept (dname);

ALTER TABLE dept ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint PRIMARY KEY (dname);
```

¿En qué caso es mejor utilizar uno u otro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **¿Que es un índice único?**

Un índice único en una columna es un índice en esa misma columna que también hace cumplir la restricción de que no se puede tener dos valores iguales en esa columna en dos filas diferentes. Ejemplo:

```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (foo int, bar int);
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_table1_foo ON table1(foo);  -- Create unique index on foo.

  INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 2); -- OK
  INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (2, 2); -- OK
  INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (3, 1); -- OK
  INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 4); -- Fails!

  Duplicate entry '1' for key 'ux_table1_foo'
```

La última inserción falla porque no cumple con el índice único en la columna foo cuando se intenta introducir el valor 1 en esta celda para una segunda vez.

En MySQL una restricción única permite múltiples NULLS.

Es posible hacer un índice único en múltiples columnas.

### **Primary Key vs Unique Index**

Cosas que son lo mismo:

- Una clave primaria implica un índice único.

Cosas que son diferentes:

- Una clave primaria implica también NOT NULL, pero un índice único
  puede ser nulo.
- Sólo puede haber una clave primaria, pero puede haber múltiples
  índices únicos.
- Si no hay un índice agrupado se define a continuación, la clave
  principal será el índice agrupado.

Traducido de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916464/3683321) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: Y para el caso específico de Oracle? El Explain Plan termina siendo diferente?

Comment: para el caso de Oracle también se mantienen las diferencias, puedes ver estos enlaces ([enlace 1](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4941517587762) y [enlace 2](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_constraint_primary_key.htm)) para más información. Por otra parte como dice @Byron yo también suelo utilizar `primary key` para las tablas y `unique index` para aquellos campos que no quiero que se repitan pero puedan estar nulos.

Comment: En este punto: "_Sólo puede haber una clave primaria, pero **no** puede haber múltiples índices únicos._", me parece que el _no_ está de más, pues supongo que quieres decir justamente lo contrario.

Comment: @jachguate gracias por el apunte, me he equivocado en la traducción y se me ha colado ese no, ahora lo edito

Answer (score 3):

> Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia (en caso de existir) entre las claves primarias y un índice marcado como único (**Primary Key** vs **Unique Index**).

Ambos se complementan, pero sus objetivos principales son distintos. Me explico...

**Claves (o constraints)**

El objetivo principal de una clave (o constraint) es establecer una restricción en cuanto a cuáles datos la tabla puede aceptar. En Oracle existen varios tipos de claves (o constraints), entre ellas la clave primaria (primary key constraint) y la clave única (unique constraint, que no es lo mismo que un unique index). En ambos casos, se establece de que valores duplicados no se aceptan.

La diferencia entre ambos es que la clave primaria no acepta valores `null`, mientras que una clave única sí las acepta. Y la otra diferencia es que una tabla solo puede definir una sola clave primaria, mientras que puedes definir varias claves únicas.

**Índices**

En contraste, un índice (incluyendo los índices únicos) tiene como objetivo principal de acelerar el acceso a los registros. Pero en el caso de los índices únicos, tiene el efecto *secundario* de no permitir valores duplicados siguiendo exactamente el mismo contrato que una clave única.

En la práctica, no hay realmente diferencia entre una clave única (unique constraint) y un índice único (unique index), y por eso típicamente muchos los confunden. Pero estrictamente hablando, no son la misma cosa.

**¿Cuál es la relación entre ambos?**

Los índices son el modo más eficaz de verificar que se esté respetando una clave primaria o única. Por esa misma razón, Oracle exige que una clave primaria o única siempre vaya acompañado de un índice (generalmente un índice único, pero no es siempre el caso). Como ya lo pudistes notar, si al definir una clave primaria (o única), Oracle no encuentra un índice adecuado para garantizar el respeto de la clave, la base de datos automáticamente agrega un índice apropiado (generalmente un índice único, pero no siempre).

Dicho de otra forma, no se puede definir una clave primaria (o única) sin que le vaya acompañado un índice.  Pero lo opuesto no es cierto.  Un índice (único o no) no necesita que vaya acompañado de una clave.

> Según veo, ambos terminan creando un índice sobre determinado campo, pero desconozco si afecta en algo el *rendimiento* (teniendo N cantidad de datos) para poder consultar los datos.

Por la razón misma de que una clave primaria o única no puede existir sin un índice correspondiente, al final, sin importar cuál método uses, siempre te beneficiarás del rendimiento que ofrecen los índices. No habrá diferencia.

> ¿En qué caso es mejor utilizar uno u otro?

Esto es solo mi opinión, pero en lo personal, siendo que no hay diferencia de rendimiento, cuando se trata de definir cuál es el identificador principal de un registro o cuáles combinaciones de columnas no deberían permitar valores duplicados, prefiero usar las claves (primaria o únicas, `primary key constraint` o `unique constraint`). Para mí, esto comunica mejor el sentido de lo que estoy tratando de lograr. Y cómo Oracle se encarga de agregar el índice apropiado si es necesario, no necesito preocuparme con ese detalle adicional.

Solo me preocupo de agregar índices adicionales a la tabla cuando mi objetivo principal no es definir una regla o restricción, sino cuando deseo mejorar el rendimiento de ciertas queries.